# Replace php functions with comment using str_replace() and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to disable some php functions for my editor. If a user posts his code with any of the disabled function ,then preg_replace will  convert it to comment.

forexample, if fopen() is found anywhere (excluding comment area) in code ,then

Replace

```
 fopen();
```

with

```
 #fopen();
```

Here is the I have so far

```
  $code='#you can use the mkdir() function to make a new dir.
 mkdir("love");
 echo "Hello world";
 fopen("home.php");'
 echo preg_replace("/(mkdir|fopen\(.*\))/i","#$1",$code);
```

It is replacing mkdir() from both sides, also from comments "#you can use the mkdir() function to make a new dir."

Is there any way in regex to exclude matching in comments?

I just want to replace functions that are outside the comment area.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: ofcourse, the output should be **#mkdir("love") #fopen("home.php")** but not **#mkdir() #mkdir("love") #fopen("home.php")** .

Comment: Your question is very unclear at this moment. You can exclude matching in a line that starts with `#` like this: [`(?m)^#.*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:mkdir|fopen)\([^()]*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/lP5mI1/1).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done for all kind of php comments using a regular expression like this one:

```
~^(?:(?!(?://|#|/\*)).)*\K((?:mkdir|fopen)\s*\()~m
```

**Legenda**:

- `^` Start of the line (thanks to the `m` multiline modifier at the end)
- `(?:(?!(?://|#|/\*)).)*` a multiple tempered greedy position check. Validate the text in the line till it does not contain `#` or `//` or `/*`
- `\K` reset the text selected by the regex engine at this point (discarding all the text validated by the above expression).
- `((?:mkdir|fopen)\s*\()` select one of the 2 functions followed by zero or more spaces (or tabs) and an open round bracket.

Try this [Demo Online](https://regex101.com/r/nV8uS1/5).

**UPDATE**:

Added working snippet of code with a [running demo](http://ideone.com/bdkK1n)

```
<?php

$code = <<<CODE
#you can use the mkdir() function to make a new dir.
mkdir("love");
echo "Hello world";
fopen("home.php");
//mkdir()
/* fopen() */
CODE;

$re = "~^(?:(?!(?://|#|/\*)).)*\K((?:mkdir|fopen)\s*\()~m";

echo preg_replace($re,"#$1",$code);

?>
```

*CAVEAT*:

- this doesn't handle the (remote) case of a comment indicator inside a string, just like an hash inside a string `"...#..."` or `"...//..."` or `".../*..."`
- Doesn't handle correctly the multiline comments `/* ... */` when the function is not inline. (`/*...mkdir()...*/` works as expected `mkdir` is skipped while `/*...\n...mkdir()...*/` (note the `\n`) `mkdir` is commented out).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a smart answer,the following is just a way which is not good but can solve.

1. replace all special string in "" or '' with another special string like `"~~^^~~"`
2. do your previous replace
3. change the "~~^^~~" back to normal.

PS:If you have more than one function,you can use `"~~^^~~1","~~^^~~2"` etc.

Here is the code:

```
$str = '"asdfasmkdir()sdljsdlffopen()sdfsd";fopen()';
$regix = '/"(.*?)mkdir(.*?)"/';
$changeArr = array(
    'mkdir' => '~~__~~1',
    'fopen' => '~~__~~2',
);
$newStr = $str;
//first step
foreach($changeArr as $k=>$v){
    $regix = '/(".*?)'.$k.'(.*?")/';
    $newStr = preg_replace($regix,'$1'.$v.'$2',$newStr);
}
var_dump($newStr);
//second step
//this is your code,by using $new Str
//third step
foreach($changeArr as $k=>$v){
    $regix = '/(".*?)'.$v.'(.*?")/';
    $newStr = preg_replace($regix,'$1'.$k.'$2',$newStr);
}
var_dump($newStr);
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with the format? I use Cmd+K,for all,and can't change it back

Comment: Just done that, the edit needs to be peer reviewed though.

Comment: Thanx,much better now!